# Session and cookies are not removing in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, logout, customer-session

I am trying to set the cookie on user login basis and want to empty on logout. Login working perfect but logout didn't work. For that purpose I used this XML code :

```
    <customer_logout>
    <observers>
<customer_is_loggedout_observer>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Easylife_Sales_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>customerLogout</method>
            </customer_is_loggedout_observer>
        </observers>
    </customer_logout>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <customer_is_logged_in_observer>
                        <class>Easylife_Sales_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setHandle</method>
                    </customer_is_logged_in_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
       <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
```

And PHP code is in observer :

```
<?php

class Easylife_Sales_Model_Observer 
{

    public function setHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
  Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
if($session->isLoggedIn()){

     $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
   $name = 'loginuser';
          $value = $customerData->getId();

          Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($name, $value);

 }else if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('loginuser') > 0 ){

      Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('loginuser'));
 }


}

     public function customerLogout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

      if (isset($_COOKIE['loginuser'])) {
         unset($_COOKIE['loginuser']);
        setcookie('loginuser', null, -1, '/');
      }
      Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsetAll();
       $cookieName = 'loginuser';
     $session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));
     $session->unsetAll();
     $session->clear();

       //echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('loginuser');exit();

    }

}
```

I am trying to delete the cookie value and user session on logout click. It shows message of logout successfully and redirect to home page but when reload page it logged in? What I am doing wrong? The `else` condition is for multi-website where I want to logged in user when he logged in on one site.

Comment: use Mage::getModel('core/cookie') to delete cookie as well. might be issue with domain name and http only flag issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use the type singleton for your observer and configure it under the frontent events:

Example for customer login

use

Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
                    logout
                    singleton

```
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <your_unqiue_event_name1>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>login</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </your_unqiue_event_name1>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
</events>
```

Then in your observer class set/unset your custom session value

in

```
public function login()
{
     ..... 
     Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyValue($myValue);
     .....
}

public function logout()
{
    .....
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->unsMyValue();
    .....
}
```